# How to insert multiple values in single column using JSP in oracle databse

Tags: jsp

I am facing problem inserting multiple values into a single column how can i do that?

I am using below code to insert multiple values in one column I know I am wrong please correct me.

```
<% 
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","system");    

    String s=request.getParameter("Question1");
    String s1=request.getParameter("Question2");
    String s2=request.getParameter("Question3");
    String s3=request.getParameter("Question4");
    String s4=request.getParameter("Question5");

    PreparedStatement P=c.prepareStatement("insert into QUESTION values(?,?,?,?,?)");
    P.setString(1,s);
    P.setString(1,s1);
    P.setString(1,s2);
    P.setString(1,s3);
    P.setString(1,s4);
    int i = P.executeUpdate();

    if(i>0) {
        response.sendRedirect("EnterQuestion.jsp");
    } else {
        out.println("Error");
    }
%>
```

Comment: That inserts 5 values, into 5 unknown columns of the table QUESTION. To insert 5 rows, you need to execute the statement 5 times, each time with a different parameter: `insert into QUESTION (NAME_OF_THE_COLUMN) values (?)`. Also, respect the Java naming conventions, don't put Java code in JSPs, and always, always post the stack trace of the exception when asking about it.

Answer (score -1):

you query execution is of following way.

```
PreparedStatement P=c.prepareStatement("insert into QUESTION values(?,?,?,?,?)");
P.setString(1,s);
P.setString(2,s1);
P.setString(3,s2);
P.setString(4,s3);
P.setString(5,s4);
int i = P.executeUpdate();
```